# Reuse router in Angular but also affect other component?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, router

In Angular, I have 3 url which have same route but different query params? (Component A)

```
- app/main/report?Type=1 
- app/main/report?Type=2 
- app/main/report?Type=3
```

In Constructor Component A, I put

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false
```

It's working but also reload my sidebar (Component B)
How to reuse route only one component or any config in routing files ?

I tried

```
- this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
- skipLocationChanged
- onSameUrlNavigation
```